# In java, can you make a line graph from two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, graph

I want to make a line graph with x values 1-100 and y values ranging from 1-18. I have them stored in two arrays which currently print to text files (for obvious reasons i dont want to manually make a bar graph consisting of 100 points). Maybe something using the application window?

I dont know what more information i can give you to make it clearer what im asking for, so if there is anything just ask for it and ill post it.

Comment: Look for graphing libraries.

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far, I've been trying to find some guide on this but haven't found anything. Im also not sure the best way to post my code

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public final class LineGraph {
    private LineGraph() {

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(LineGraph::doRun);
    }

    private static void doRun() {
        final int[] x = new int[] {0, 40, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280, 320, 360};
        final int[] y = new int[] {100, 200, 100, 50, 200, 0, 300, 200, 100, 300};

        final
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(new JPanelImpl(x, y), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class JPanelImpl extends JPanel {
        private final int[] x;
        private final int[] y;

        public JPanelImpl(final int[] x, final int[] y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(final Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            for(int i = 0; i < this.x.length; i++) {
                if(i + 1 < this.x.length) {
                    final int x0 = this.x[i];
                    final int y0 = this.y[i];
                    final int x1 = this.x[i + 1];
                    final int y1 = this.y[i + 1];

                    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    graphics.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
                    graphics.fillOval(x1 - 3, y1 - 3, 6, 6);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working, but i have some problems. the graph is really small and in the top left corner, as well as upside down. ill try and fix it myself but you know why please let me know.

Comment: The window uses coordinates where the minimum X is to the left of the window, the maximum X is to the right, the minimum Y is at the top and the maximum Y is at the bottom. I believe the X-axis is like you want it to be. But for the Y-axis, doing something like (height - y) would do (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: I got it, I just multiplied the variables when I set them into the array. Thanks man, this really helps

Comment: Great! Not sure if you noticed that I added "graphics.fillOval(x1 - 3, y1 - 3, 6, 6);" to fill an oval for each point in the graph?